# How can I serve files under node_modules with GitHub Pages?

Tags: github, github-pages

github pages won't serve my `node_modules` files (gives 404's), despite the special attention i've provided to it

1. github project https://github.com/open-history/sandbox
2. hosted on github pages https://open-history.github.io/sandbox/
   (notice the 404's)
3. i've tracked the `node_modules` files i want into the repository
4. i've added the empty `.nojekyll` file (the previously established solution)

i must be missing something, since so many other users seem to be doing the same thing, most of which report success after adding `.nojekyll`

Comment: I'm not getting any 404s in the console when I load up the second link.

Comment: @jhpratt — it turns out I just needed to wait longer — github pages does some aggressive serverside caching (how can you blame them), and I just needed to sit back for awhile longer.. I guestimate it took over an hour for the serverside github cache to relax its grip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Just sit back, and have a rum

- it turns out, github pages just employs some *serverside* caching, and it can take hours to begin serving up new files
- all i needed to do, was wait it out
- interestingly, the node_module files were available via a `curl` request for awhile before my web browsers could finally see the fruits of my labor — see relevant comments in this github issue https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/844